# package conflict in flutter project

Tags: flutter, google-maps, parse-platform, package

dears I am working on a flutter app where I need to add flutter_google_map V 4.0.0 and parse_server_sdk V 3.1.0 and each one depend on different version of http_package

the map depend on version 0.12.0
and parse_sdk depend on 0.13.3

there fore I am getting conflict issue
how I could resolved without done grade the versions
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try without versioning

```
flutter_google_map:
parse_server_sdk:
```

Comment: that will down grade the version of both packages until they are on the same page, but I want the highest version of both of them

Comment: do you use this https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

Comment: thanks dear that worked like a charm it seems that this package also use http 0.13.3 thanks so match